# Toggle - add if !contained, remove if contains in

Tags: lodash

I can accomplish what I need with filter/map and perhaps reduce, but I want to know - as it can be very nifty and succinct in accomplishing things... if I had an array of objects like so:

Comment: Wow, you changed your question totally.....

Answer (score 5):

Please try do it through [`xorBy`](https://lodash.com/docs#xorBy)

```
> var arr = [
   {name: "bill", id: 909},
   {name: "tina", id: 444},
   {name: "ron", id: 24},
   {name: "paul", id: 4445}];

> var remove_arr = _.xorBy(arr, [{name: "ron", id: 24}], 'id');

> remove_arr
  [{name: "bill", id: 909},
   {name: "tina", id: 444},
   {name: "paul", id: 4445}];

> var add_arr = _.xorBy(arr, [{name: "mary", id: 887}], 'id');
> add_arr
  [{name: "bill", id: 909},
   {name: "tina", id: 444},
   {name: "ron", id: 24},
   {name: "paul", id: 4445},
   {name: "mary", id: 887}];
```